# Update automatically DNS entries in Docker container using --network host

Tags: docker, dns, dnsmasq

I have a Docker container that uses the host network and when I run the container it takes the same resolv.conf of the host machine.

```
docker run -ti --network host ubuntu:18.04 /bin/bash
```

I have configured a VPN interface in my host that use an additional DNS server `10.10.0.5` and one search domain using the DNS server `myvpndomain.com`.

But the problem is when I start the container without being connected to the VPN it takes my usual /etc/resolv.conf. But once the container is started if I turn on my VPN interface I can see all machines on the VPN network including the VPN's DNS server: `10.10.0.5` (I can ping to it), **but the DNS resolution configuration doesn't get updated automatically from host, I need to restart the container to get the new DNS configuration**.

DNS configuration in the host machine after connected to VPN:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf

search myvpndomain.com
nameserver 10.10.0.5
nameserver 80.58.61.250
nameserver 80.58.61.254
```

DNS configuration inside the container the container after connected to VPN:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 80.58.61.250
nameserver 80.58.61.254
```

To update the DNS configuration after connecting my VPN I tried two solutions so far:

**1**) Adding a bind mount to host /etc/resolv.conf file into the container `-v /etc/resolv.conf:/etc/resolv.conf` to run command, but it does not work, I don't know why even updating host resolv.conf, the mounted resolv.conf in container does not update.

**2**) Adding `--dns 127.0.0.53 --dns-search myvpndomain.com` to run command, this works well as it uses the systemd-resolver and also adds the required search domain. But I would want to not rely on systemd-resolver to accomplish this.

Do you know a more clean solution that does not involve to use the systemd-resolver?

Maybe use Docker internal DNS `127.0.0.11` + dnsmasq?

**PD**: It's mandatory to use the host network the container `--network host`